# SVN key bindings not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I installed Eclipse 3.6 64-bit on a fresh Windows 7.
I tried setting some key bindings using the Keys section of the preferences window, namely:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - commit using SVN
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> - update using SVN
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - revert using SVN

It all worked flawlessly in the past on Eclipse 3.5 32bit on Windows XP, but it just doesn't work in my recent setup. When I'm navigating to the 'Team' menu, the shortcuts do appear next to the aforementioned actions (i.e. Eclipse writes <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> next to 'Update to HEAD').

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It may be due to this breaking change in Eclipse 3.6:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/porting/3.6/incompatibilities.html?view=co#objectContribution

EDIT:

Looks like it definitely is. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309074. Here's the fix:

In the "Customize Perspective" dialog, go to the "Command Groups Availability" tab and check "Team" and "SVN".

In Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) this is under Window->Perspective->Customize Perspective... dialog, "Action Set Availability" tab. (Try to restart Eclipse if it doesn't work after you change it).
[Customize Perspective dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo1PD.png)

Comment: You sir are my hero. Please notice that it is in the "Customize perspective" dialog (there is no "Customize Workspace" dialog).

Comment: Glad it worked (and you're right - I updated the answer w/ the right dialog name).

Comment: Nice, this was also the issue with Eclipse on OSX.

Comment: Solved the same issue with Eclipse 3.7.1 on Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: The same problem exists on MAC with eclipse 4, and effectively enabling the SVN visibility in Menu made shortcuts work (both if defined in eclipse-shortcuts or in mac 'system preferences' application shortcuts)

Comment: Still happening (and still a really helpful answer; thank you) four years later (Win 7 64-bit and Eclipse Luna).

Comment: Still valid as of April 2016. Confirmed the workaround in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 (which is based on Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

All eclipse workspace settings are stored in `<eclipse-workspace-name>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings` folder. So, try copying this folder from your 32bit Windows XP environment into 64bit Windows 7 setup.