# How to set key binding for 'Team|Show history' in Eclipse with MercurialEclipse in PyDev perspective?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, key-bindings, mercurialeclipse

I'm trying to set a key binding for showing Mercurial history of active file (*Team|Show History* in context menu) in PyDev perspective. All I see in Mercurial category in *Window|Preferences|General|Keys* pertaining to history is *Show Root History* command. After setting a key binding for this command and pressing appropriate keys nothing happens. Also I don't see any command of interest pertaining to history in *Team* category in the same window.
This problem seems to be very similar to the one with SVN key bindings described in [SVN key bindings not working in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400185/) question. However, in the *Customize Perspective* dialog for PyDev perspective, on *Command Groups Availability* tab there's no *Mercurial* entry analogues to *SVN* entry mentioned in the above question.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, Version: 3.7.0, Build id: I20110310-1119, PyDev 2.0.1 and MercurialEclipse 1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have been solved in the meantime, but in my current Indigo version (Eclipse for PHP developers 3.0.2 with MercurialEclipse 1.9.1) a *Show History* command is available in the *Mercurial* category of key shortcuts. Setting a binding to this one will work as expected, aka showing the hg history for the currently selected file.
That's a pity that the *Show Root History* does not work at all, I'd need that one :)