# How to force Eclipse's quick diff to refresh after a commit?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm using Subclipse 3.0.0 and set my quick diff settings to be against "Prestine SVN copy".
However when I make a commit using the menu option `Team -> Commit` I still see the old changes coloured in my left side ruller where the line numbers are.

Doing a `Refresh` on the source tree does not help either. I have to manually close all the opened source files and re-open them for the quick diff to update.

From what I see the reference "Prestine SVN copy" only gets updated when you open a file that is not currently opened. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I reported this bug a while ago, see link below. [Bug reported to Tigris](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=547)

Comment: It's now the end of July 2013 and this bug is still not fixed. :-/

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, to do SVN clean up

Right Click on Project -> Team -> Refresh/Cleanup option

You also can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636409/subclipse-1-8-5-requires-cleanup-refresh-cycle-to-detect-changes-made-with-t) to add a keyboard shortcut for this command