# eclipse svn hotkeys missing

Tags: eclipse, svn

I had the latest eclipse and svn hotkeys where working!

However my laptop died and so I have reinstalled eclipse on my replacement

I had backed up my workspace and so when i reinstalled i just pointed eclipse to my existing workspace

this worked in terms of projects but now svn hotkeys do not work

> Alt + C - commit using SVN
>
> Alt + U - update using SVN
>
> Alt + R - revert using SVN

I have tried the suggestion on this similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400185/svn-key-bindings-not-working-in-eclipse) but it did not fix it!

[image]

even the right click menu doesnt show the hotkeys anymore

[image]

Comment: Shortcuts can be set or restored to the defaults in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_. The mentioned Stack Overflow answer refers to a bug that has been fixed five years ago and hopefully your Eclipse version is newer.

Comment: i have 2019-03 eclipse.  unfortunately restoring defaults did NOT work for me, thanks anyways

Comment: To which scheme (drop-down at the top) do you have restored to the defaults?

Comment: default.  only other listed is emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two SVN plug-ins for Eclipse, Subversive and Subclipse. Probably, you **lost the key bindings by switching from [Subversive](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider) to [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse)** (the screenshots show that you currently have Subclipse).

Uninstalling Subclipse and installing Subversive should bring back the key bindings. Alternatively, you can keep Subclipse and set the keys manually in *Window > Preferences: General > Keys*.